# How to put a value 1 in a array of zeros

Tags: arrays, matlab, zero

if i have an array of zeros, lets say

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

then i ask the user to type an input number between 1 and 6

If the input is 3 (for example), then I want my program to 
insert the value 1 in the third position, that is:

```
[0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

How can i achieve that in Matlab?

Comment: One approach is by writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`input`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/input.html):

```
index = input('Please type desired index: ')
```

If `a = [1 2 3 4];` and you want to change the value in position 3 to be equal `5`, you can do:

```
a(3) = 5;
a = 1   2   5   4
```

I'll leave the rest up to you. [This link](http://www.mathworks.se/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a keyboard input with 'input' ...well

```
a=zeros(1,6);    
ind = input('Please enter a Number(1-6)');
if ind > 0 && ind <= length(a)    
    a(ind) = 1
end
```